# recover deleted accidentally deleted folder using recovery mode

Tags: data-recovery

I am using a VMWare to work on ubuntu, and Sunday's afternoon, I had the first error and when I was trying to solve it, I've accidentally deleted the var folder. This is the folder where I have all my projects stored, and i have no backup for it. Now I am getting a new kind of error with ubuntu. I don't exactly know what it is about, but since the first error I can't come to the login screen, I am doing everything now in the recovery mode terminal. What I want is to recover the folder I deleted, I can after that install another ubuntu and paste that folder in it it will be not a problem. Can anybody please help me? I have tried a lot of things but each time I try to run a command it says that some files are missing, or that I need to run `apt get update/apt-get install`, but when I try to run it I get some errors also. I wanted to post some imgs that descripe the problem but I don't have enogh reputations yet. Sorry but I am not able to copy or show more description about the errors

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696557/recover-accidentally-deleted-folder-ubuntu

Comment: Use a live system to recover data, never operate on the system you want to recover! I guess there is a lot of stuff in `/var` that is needed by all kinds of software.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes both posts are mine, I've posted it here and there to get as much info as possible, because I really need a solution to solve the problem, else I need to begin everything from the beginning again.

Comment: @pLumo I think that too it is a really important folder in ubuntu, but I think after deleting it ubuntu generates the important files again by it self. I am sorry I didn't understand what you mean with a live system. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Thanks for the information, the problem is that I can't copy any line and I cant go up or down to show the whole error message, but as an example when I try to write sudo apt update, I get some errors and some of them say that it is failed to fetch an URL. When I try to run ubuntu now it stuks at the ubuntu logo and I can't go any further but when I click ESC key it gives some errors like Stopped GNOME Display, Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes, Finished Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes, Starting GNOME Display Manager, Faild to start

Comment: To be honest because of the amount of things that I've tried I don't remember what I have exactly tried, but nothing actually worked because it doesn't want to run sudo apt update or install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to my question.

My Ubuntu doesn't start up, it gets stuck at the Ubuntu word when I start it up. Firstly I had to find a solution for that: I have got an Ubuntu ISO and I used it as a CD with my VMWare so I could use Try Ubuntu to get to my Desktop. I declared the path of the ISO in the settings of my Ubuntu VM, then I started Ubuntu up and I pressed ESC Immiadetly when it turns on.

Then I chose the 'boot from CD' option, after that it checks the disk, once it's finished it shows a screen with a couple of options: 1-Try Ubuntu    2-Install Ubuntu, so I've chosen Try Ubuntu, and then Ubuntu starts up and I get a UI(the Desktop) to see.

Once I get to my desktop I've searched and used a lot of software and plugins to restore the files, but almost every one of them was useless/complicated/paid, and don't have any good clues, so I kept searching until I saw R-Studio.

I downloaded it and scanned my partition, and the surprise is that it gave me a lot of things that I deleted since a long time ago, but the only thing was that the most of them were hashed(with a very strange name) so I had to search in hundreds of folders (if not thousands) to finally find my files (after I found the files I discovered that there is a search function 'sad xD') and I found them.

I've tried to restore all of them, but one of them was bigger than the maximum free size to restore.

They have a preview function, to preview files like texts, etc, so I previewed it and copied all the script and paste it in a file that I created, then I uploaded all the files to Mediafire, my favorite cloud and then downloaded it on another VMWare to get them working! (Because of the corrupted system of this Ubuntu I couldn't copy-paste anything from/to outside of that VMWare)

Thanks to everyone that has tried to help me.

Comment: I forgot to metion the source of the program it was from R-Studio from that link https://www.r-studio.com/data_recovery_linux/Download.shtml